# Kubuntu 18.04 doesn't show on GRUB after installing Kubuntu 20.04 on a second disk

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kubuntu

Yesterday I added an SSD to my laptop by removing the DVDRom. I had Windows 10 and Kubuntu 18.04 on the primary HDD (sda), and wanted to have Kubuntu 20.04 on the SDD (sdb). As my BIOS didn't detect the SSD as a bootable disk I had to re-install GRUB2 on sda.

I expected that GRUB would show the 3 OSs: W10, K18.04 and K20.04, but instead it only shows W10 & K20.04.

In K20 I can mount sda* (/ and /home), but it always mounts them adding a "@": "/media/user/@/" and "/media/user/@/home".
I've tried using the grub console, but when I do `ls (hd0,5)/` it shows "@". When I try (after doing `set root=(hd0,5)`) `linux @/vmlinux` it says invalid name.

So, (i) what can I do to run again my old K18 installation?
(ii) What did I do wrong when I installed K20?

Thanks,

Comment: In case it's important, K18 (sda)'s filesystem is btrfs while K20 (sdb)'s filesystem is ext4.

Comment: And I think that was the problem. Trying this solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/967172/grub2-does-not-detect-btrfs-partition

Comment: And the real problem was that GRUB didn't like btrfs. Previous link solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

The real problem was that that the new GRUB installation didn't lie the filesystem of the old instalation (btrfs). This solution solved the problem:https://askubuntu.com/questions/967172/grub2-does-not-detect-btrfs-partition